# Is it possible to just install Android SDK on Jenkins Server?

Tags: android, jenkins

I would like to configure my Jenkins server on Linux to build and test android applications.
Is it possible to just install and manage android SDKs instead of having a full Android Studio installation?
Thanks,

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: https://jenkins.io/solutions/android/ or may be https://bugfender.com/blog/how-to-add-your-first-android-job-to-jenkins/

Comment: I can see there are explanatory videos. will follow them, Thanks!

Comment: You can try public docker image for android

Comment: @yong: I already installed android sdk tools manually. Will try maybe later docker image as I am not really familiar with docker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible @Hichem, you can say this is the desired behaviour when you are installing Jenkins on the server.

There is a good article for doing same please have a look and feel free to ask

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JenkinsAndroid/article.html

For updated SDK version you can browse this url

https://developer.android.com/studio